# MongoDB - Mongorestore is not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.4, mongorestore

A Very Good Day,

I have the user in the mongodb like below who has the superuser privileges (I confirmed the role setting using `show users` command)

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.mongoadmin",
    "user" : "mongoadmin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
```

when I try to restore the oplog using the mongorestore, I get the error :

**Failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: not authorized on admin to execute command** { applyOps: [ { ts: Timestamp(1552828309, 1), h: 4632811839329880092, v: 2, op: "c", ns: "admin.$cmd", o: { create: "system.keys", idIndex: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "*id*", ns: "admin.system.keys" } }, o2: {} } ], $db: "admin" }

```
mongorestore -u admin -p password --authenticationDatabase=admin --oplogFile 0000000000_0_oplog.bson  --oplogReplay --oplogLimit=1552828432 --dir='/oplog/temp'
2019-03-17T13:47:36.945+0000    preparing collections to restore from
2019-03-17T13:47:36.945+0000    replaying oplog
2019-03-17T13:47:36.962+0000    Failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: not authorized on admin to execute command { applyOps: [ { ts: Timestamp(1552828309, 1), h: 4632811839329880092, v: 2, op: "c", ns: "admin.$cmd", o: { create: "system.keys", idIndex: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "admin.system.keys" } }, o2: {} } ], $db: "admin" }
```

**NOTE** : I specified the oploglimit (--oplogLimit=1552828432) with the last value I got from the bsondump 
Is this correct? Or Am I missing anything?

(i.e)

```
{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1552828432,"i":79}},"t":{"$numberLong":"1"},"h":{"$numberLong":"-2072015676601300967"},"v":2,"op":"i","ns":"inventory.hari","ui":{"$binary":"avdlGH8AS1eBPXRytlO1Yg==","$type":"04"},"wall":{"$date":"2019-03-17T13:13:52.139Z"},"o":{"_id":"79","name":"Hari","role":"Developer","isEmployee":true}}
{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1552828432,"i":80}},"t":{"$numberLong":"1"},"h":{"$numberLong":"-6279494628130059002"},"v":2,"op":"u","ns":"inventory.hari","ui":{"$binary":"avdlGH8AS1eBPXRytlO1Yg==","$type":"04"},"o2":{"_id":"79"},"wall":{"$date":"2019-03-17T13:13:52.139Z"},"o":{"_id":"79","name":"WD_Userjava.util.Random@9a7504c","role":"Developer","isEmployee":true}}
```

**Edited :**

I did the restore like below

```
mongorestore -u mongoadmin -p password --authenticationDatabase admin -d itsm_inventory -c hari 0000000000_0_oplog.bson
```

It seems successful

I inserted like this

```
{ "_id" : "0", "name" : "WD_Userjava.util.Random@2bbf4b8b", "role" : "Developer", "isEmployee" : true }
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "WD_Userjava.util.Random@7a765367", "role" : "Developer", "isEmployee" : true }
```

but it is restored like below

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c91eac58fe872c878289d83"), "ts" : Timestamp(1552888901, 2), "t" : NumberLong(1), "h" : NumberLong("-3584326290393879639"), "v" : 2, "op" : "i", "ns" : "itsm_inventory.hari", "ui" : UUID("b5f574f1-c55a-4a5b-8729-4483f56f5c9d"), "wall" : ISODate("2019-03-18T06:01:41.062Z"), "o" : { "_id" : "1", "name" : "WD_Userjava.util.Random@7a765367", "role" : "Developer", "isEmployee" : true } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c91eac58fe872c878289d84"), "ts" : Timestamp(1552888901, 3), "t" : NumberLong(1), "h" : NumberLong("-3618415120025822301"), "v" : 2, "op" : "i", "ns" : "itsm_inventory.hari", "ui" : UUID("b5f574f1-c55a-4a5b-8729-4483f56f5c9d"), "wall" : ISODate("2019-03-18T06:01:41.062Z"), "o" : { "_id" : "2", "name" : "WD_Userjava.util.Random@76b0bfab", "role" : "Developer", "isEmployee" : true } }
```

**Mani's answer edit :**

```
mongorestore -u mongoadmin -p password --authenticationDatabase=admin --oplogFile 0000000000_0_oplog.bson  --oplogReplay --oplogLimit=1553063755 --dir='/oplog/temp'
2019-03-21T10:46:42.435+0000    preparing collections to restore from
2019-03-21T10:46:42.435+0000    replaying oplog
2019-03-21T10:46:42.457+0000    Failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: not authorized on admin to execute command { applyOps: [ { ts: Timestamp(1552888562, 3), h: -8964353497436574374, v: 2, op: "c", ns: "admin.$cmd", o: { create: "system.keys", idIndex: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "admin.system.keys" } }, o2: {} } ], $db: "admin" }
```

Anyhelp is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ,For authentication you must specify the **authenticationDatabase** parameter in mongorestore command. The executed command mongorestore -u mongoadmin -p password --authenticationDatabase admin -d itsm_inventory -c hari 0000000000_0_oplog.bson seems to be ok.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan can you check the edited question section, I have already tried that : --authenticationDatabase admin please check it

Answer (score 1):

As per MongoDB jira blog [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19191) `mongorestore` `--oplog` will not apply oplog entries captured during the `mongodump` operation, and exit with an error when attempting to use mongorestore with the restore role and a MongoDB deployment that uses access control. For additional information, please review the documentation on the [restore role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#restore).

As it's a affects the MongoDB version like `2.6.10`,`3.04`. To avoid such error need to update the MongoDB with current version. The restore role does not provide users access to the `applyOps` command, which `mongorestore` uses with the --`oplogReplay` option.

**WORKAROUNDS**

To restore data using the `mongorestore` `--oplogReplay` option, users may [create a role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/) that grants [anyAction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#authr.anyAction) on [anyResource](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/resource-document/#resource-anyresource). Do not assign this role to any other user. This role provides full unrestricted access to the system.

Alternatively users can disable authentication while restoring data by starting mongod instances without the `--auth` option during the installation and then re-enabling `--auth` after completing the restoration.

***After conversation with OP (Harry) & Edit***

**How to restore a ".bson" file in MongoDB?**

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongorestore -d test -c oplog C:\data\oplog.bson
2019-03-20T10:06:35.981+0300    checking for collection data in C:\data\oplog.bson
2019-03-20T10:06:35.985+0300    restoring test.oplog from C:\data\oplog.bson
2019-03-20T10:06:37.058+0300    no indexes to restore
2019-03-20T10:06:37.058+0300    finished restoring test.oplog (10138 documents)
2019-03-20T10:06:37.059+0300    done
```

In the above mongorestore command where the **test** is the database name & **oplog** is the collection name. The `C:\data\oplog.bson` is the `.bson` file path location.

For further your ref [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/yazyB5Rc-jU)

Comment: Appreciate for your answer, I didn't understand the workaround, I have the user with role as root (superuser) then not sure why I need to create another role, If its mandatory, Could you provide the sample role creation query you are taking about please, Also I am fine with creating user any super privilege

Comment: Also the replaying shows as success when I increase the OPLIMIT to current time in millisecond but the data is not restored - Do you know why ?

Comment: Try converting your bson dump to json using `bsondump --outFile collection.json collection.bson` to check your bson dump has correct data

Comment: @Mani yes It has the proper data, I see the json files as well but not sure why it is not working, I uploaded the file online : http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08430663558165071661 Could you try to restore it please also not sure why it is not working :(

Comment: @Harry, I have been checked your uploaded "oplog.bson" data , it went through successfully & restored. I am updating my answer with that mongorestore screen shot.

Comment: Hi @MdHaidarAliKhan, It went through successfully, but the entries are not created , can you check the database - itsm_inventory and collection - hari

Comment: also please send me the mongorestore command you used please

Comment: @Harry,I have been update answer with mongorestore command.

Comment: Thanks for the update @MdHaidarAliKhan but it failed again, please see my edited question

Comment: I think it is restored as it is in bsondump :( also using -d itsm_inventory will restore all the entries in it irrespective of database right

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Do you have any idea on this please

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [oplog file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08430663558165071661) you uploaded, the minimum timestamp is `1552888560` and maximum timestamp is `1553063754`. But the `--oplogLimit=1552828432` you mentioned in your question is not within the limit, which is less than the minimum timestamp value. That is the reason none of the documents were restored.

Run the following command from the folder where `0000000000_0_oplog.bson` file exists.

```
mongorestore -u admin -p password --authenticationDatabase=admin --oplogFile 0000000000_0_oplog.bson  --oplogReplay --oplogLimit=1553063755 --dir='/oplog/temp'
```

> Also, make sure no `.bson` file present in the `/oplog/temp` folder.

Comment: I get this error : not authorized on admin to execute command when I give the oplog limit like you mentioned for the same file, Do I need to set any different user privilege?

Comment: Also the oplog I uploaded is the recent one, so it seems like the old value for you. What is the user privilege / role you provided for the admin user?

Comment: I mean can you run - use admin; show users;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday when I tried to perform PITR. I am still not able to figure out why it didn't worked when my admin user had "root" role assigned. However, I disabled the "authorization" and tried, it worked. But that's not we all want to be doing in production right.

But then as another workaround, I tried different approach.

1. Either copy oplog to new collection directly (db.copyCollection) or taking a dump and then restoring it to some test collection temporarily.
2. Goal is to edit the documents where "ns: admin.$cmd" or any operations entries related to "admin" db exists in actual oplog dump taken.
3. Once edit has been done, take mongodump again on that collection so you will get ".bson" file in order to restore it to oplog.
4. We could have edited the initial oplog dump file ".bson" by converting it using bsondump but mongorestore --oplogReplay will only work with bson files and there was no way I could have convert json into bson except importing it back to new collection then taking mongodump. Hence, step 3.